# mac osX packageMaker: how to set the destination to the user home directory?

Tags: macos, home-directory

I am building an installer on mac osx 10.6.8 with packageMaker 3.04. I can install a particular content at "destination" `/Applications` that is fine. Now, I need to add another content to the user home directory (`/Documents`)

I have tried `~/` and `$HOME/` to set the destination for that particular package, but when installing, the actual location is empty.

So, how can I set this properly?

Answer (score 0):

In Package Maker, just above the "Contents" pane on the left, select your package icon. Then, in the right hand pane, change Install Destination to "User home directory". Then, for all of your install locations, just use / as the root. That will be interpreted as the top level home directory of the installing user.

Comment: That will cause a warning message: Install domain "User home directory" will not work prior to Mac OS X v10.5

Comment: if so, Is there any idea for shipping the files in user's home directory for the previous versions of Mac OS X ?

Comment: @BalajiRenganathan, hi, do You know how to set user home dir using pmdoc xml? i don't use UI, package manager is invoked by bash script. Thanks